# Linting classes created at runtime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime, static-analysis

For context, I am using the Python `ctypes` library to interface with a C library. It isn't necessary to be familiar with C or `ctypes` to answer this question however. All of this is taking place in the context of a *python module* I am creating.

In short, my question is: **how can I allow Python linters (e.g. PyCharm or plugin for `neovim`) to lint objects that are created at runtime?** *"You can't"* is not an answer ;). Of course there is always a way, with scripting and the like. I want to know what I would be looking at for the easiest way.

First I introduce my problem and the current approach I am taking. Second, I will describe what I want to do, *and ask how*.

---

Within this C library, a whole bunch of error codes are defined. I translated this information from the `.h` header file into a Python enum:

```py
# CustomErrors.py
from enum import Enum
class CustomErrors(Enum):
    ERROR_BROKEN = 1
    ERROR_KAPUTT = 2
    ERROR_BORKED = 3
```

Initially, my approach is to have a single exception class containing a `type` field which described the specific error:

```py
# CustomException.py
from CustomErrors import CustomErrors
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, customErr):
        assert type(customErr) is CustomError
        self.type = customErr
        super().__init__()
```

Then, as needed I can `raise CustomException(CustomErrors.ERROR_KAPUTT)`.

---

Now, what I want to do is create a **separate exception class** corresponding to each of the enum items in `CustomErrors`. I believe it is possible to create types at runtime with `MyException = type('MyException', (Exception,), {'__doc__' : 'Docstring for ABC class.'})`.

I can create the exception classes at runtime like so:

```py
#CustomException.py
from CustomErrors import CustomErrors
...
for ce in CustomErrors:
     n = ce.name
     vars()[n] = type(n, (Exception,), {'__doc__' : 'Docstring for {0:s} class.'.format(n)})
```

*Note: the reason I want to create these at runtime is to avoid hard-coding of an Exception list that change in the future. I already have the problem of extracting the C enum automatically on the backburner.*

This is all well and good, but I have a problem: static analysis cannot resolve the names of these exceptions defined in `CustomException`. This means PyCharm and other editors for Python will not be able to automatically resolve the names of the exceptions as a suggested autocomplete list when the user types `CustomException.`. This is not acceptable, as this is code for the end user, who will need to access the exception names for use in `try-except` constructs.

---

Here is the only solution I have been able to think of: writing a script which generates the `.py` files containing the exception names. I can do this using `bash`. Maybe people will tell me this is really the only option. But I would like to know what other approaches are suggested for solving this problem. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comment to tell mypy to ignore dynamically defined attribute errors. Perhaps the linters that you use share a similar way to silence such errors.

[mypy docs on silencing errors based on error codes](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/error_codes.html?highlight=ignore#silencing-errors-based-on-error-codes)

> This example shows how to ignore an error about an imported name mypy thinks is undefined:
>
> ```
>    # 'foo' is defined in 'foolib', even though mypy can't see the
>    # definition.
>    from foolib import foo # type: ignore[attr-defined]
> ```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want the linter to recognise the completions, not to suppress warnings.

Comment: @Myridium i think you will have to generate the python files then.